# Why does my Makefile fails and how to fix 255 error for the Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

My `Makefile` is like below:

```
test:
    pipenv run test

safety:
    pipenv run safety check --full-report
```

When I run the command `make safety`, I get the following error:

```
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'safety' failed
make: *** [safety] Error 255
```

What does the 255 error mean and how to fix it? Why does only the second command raise an error?

Comment: When you run the command without make, what is its return value?

Comment: It means the command `pipenv run safety check --full-report` finished with exit code 255.  If you don't care about the exit code you can prefix the command with `-` .

Comment: When I run `pipenv run safety check --full-report` manually, It runs ok. Is there any way to ignore this error?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I found the solution. When I run`pipenv run safety check --full-report` It displays a full report of my environments, but exits with a non zero exit code, and `Makefile`  passes this error to `make`. I now run it with `make -i safety`

Comment: No, please don't just invoke `make` as `make -i ...` as that will cause `make ` to ignore *all* error exit codes.  Instead do as suggested in the comment and [prefix the command with `-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002d-_0028in-recipes_0029): that will direct `make` to ignore non-zero exit codes for *that* command only.